# How to fix NoSuchElementException?

Tags: unchecked-exception

This is class Main.  There are two more classes in the models(Contact, ContactManager) and a txt file(contact.txt)
I have tried to load contacts from contacts.txt.
This program was working and now it is not.
I can not find the mistake or how can I fix this unchecked exception.
If I have to throw NoSuchElementException, where I have to add this?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import models.Contact;
import models.ContactManager;

class Main {
   
    static ContactManager manager = new ContactManager();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
     loadContacts("contacts.txt"); 
     System.out.println("CONTACTS LOADED\n\n");
     System.out.println(manager);
     manageContact();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        }
 
public static void loadContacts(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fis);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            try {
            Contact contact = new Contact(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next());
            manager.addContact(contact);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        scan.close();
     } 
     
     public static void manageContact() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to a) add another contact b) remove a contact c) exit"); 
            String response = scan.nextLine();
            if (response.equals("a")) {
                System.out.println("\tName: ");
                String name = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\tPhone number: ");
                String phoneNumber = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\tBirth Date: ");
                String birthDate = scan.nextLine();
                if (name.isBlank() || phoneNumber.isBlank() || phoneNumber.length() < 5) {
                    System.out.println("\nThe input is not valid.");
                } else { 
                try {
                manager.addContact(new Contact(name, phoneNumber, birthDate));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                System.out.println("\n\nUPDATED CONTACTS\n\n" + manager);
            }
        }
        } else if (response.equals("b")) {
            System.out.println("Who would you like to remove?");
            manager.removeContact(scan.nextLine());
            System.out.println("\n\nUPDATED CONTACTS\n\n" + manager);
        } else {
            break;
        }
     }
     scan.close();
    }
}
```

This program was working and now it is not.
I can not find the mistake or how can I fix this unchecked exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
        at Main.loadContacts(Main.java:28)
        at Main.main(Main.java:14)`
```

How to fix this NoSuchElementException? Would you mind helping me to understand what is wrong?

Comment: What this says to me is that you ASSUME your datafile always contains a multiple of 3 lines, and your file does not.  This might not be the best way to store contact data.  You might consider looking into a lightweight database instead.